# MouseHover event doesn't work

Tags: c#, mouse, mousemove, mousehover, mouseup

I have a problem with the event MouseHover (the same problem with MouseEnter/MouseMove/...). It doesn't work. The text doesn't change.

```
private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "text changed";
    }
```

Could somebody explain me why it doesn't work ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the event method you posted is tie up with the component you are expecting it to dispatch the event.

Comment: Hi, how can I check that ?

Comment: Right click on the control you want to add the event on , go to property, click on the events icon (Lightning bolt) and double click on the evento you want , and then you implement the event.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **viniciusalvess** !

I had to add this in the Form's constructor :

```
button1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(button1_MouseLeave);
```

Now it's ok. Thanks ! :)